# How to use Deserialization code in android?

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

This is **C#** code, please convert it to **Android** code.

```
T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

Comment: how much do you pay? if 0$/€/£, do you really think that anyone will do your homework?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know c#, But for JSON serialization in android you can use GSON,download GSON library  and import it in your project. Go throw the following link for more info. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples